# Получение данных с JSON файла

Tags: php, html, ajax, json

У меня есть JSON файл в таком виде `{"Name":"wefgew"; "Birthday": "21"; "City": "qefqwef"}`. Мне нужен такой ajax запросто что бы записывал Имена, Дни, Города в свой span (примерно `<span class="params on" id="Name">wefgew</span`).
Мне бы пример похожий, буду благодарен любой помощи , заранее спасибо!

JS блок , которым я получаю данные с инпутов и передаю php на сохранение

```
    <script>
  $('#btn_save').on('click',function(){
    var textField = $('#textField').val();
    var textBirthday = $('#textBirthday').val();
    var textCity = $('#textCity').val();

    var str = '{"Name":"' +textField +'"; "Birthday": "' + textBirthday + '"; "City": "' + textCity + '"}';

    $.ajax({   
        type: "POST",
        url: 'test.php',
        data: {'str':str},
        success: function(data){
          alert('Successfully saved');
        },
        error: function(data) {
          alert('Error');
        },

    }); 

  });
</script>
```

Php файл 
 `<?php
file_put_contents('some_file.json', $_POST['str']);`

Comment: Не проще сделать форму и данные с формы просто в php через ajax отправлять?

Comment: Я до этого момента php в глаза не видел и с остальным особо не работал. Потому  для меня тут все не очень просто.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В таком варианте страница test.php загружаться не будет так как используется аякс запрос, обработанные данные будут добавлены под формой

```js
$(function() {
    $('.Button').click(function(){ // нажатие на кнопку
        $('#formBlockSale').ajaxForm({ // отправляем данные с формы
            type: "POST", // тип передачи данных
            dataType: "html", // тип данных
            success: function(e){ // если запрос удачный
                alert(e); // виводим сообщение с результатом который вернул пхп скрипт
    alert('Successfully saved'); // виводим сообщение
                $('.info').html(e); // виводим данные которые вернул пхп скрипт в блок под формой
            },
          error: function(data) { // если запрос не удачный
          alert('Error'); // виводим сообщение
        },
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formBlockSale" action="ОБРАБОТЧИК ФОРМЫ (test.php)" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" >

  <input type="text" name="textField" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Текст 1" /><br/> <!-- поле ввода 1 с именем  textField -->
  
  <input type="text" name="textBirthday" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Текст 2" /><br/> <!--  поле ввода 2 с именем textBirthday -->
  
  <input type="text" name="textCity" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Текст 3" /><br/> <!--  поле ввода 3 с именем textCity -->
  
 <button class="Button">Отправить</button> 
  
</form>

<div class="info"></div>



<!-- Файл test.php 

    <?php
        $textBirthday = $_POST('textBirthday'); // получаем значение введеное в поле ввода 1 с именем textBirthday и заносим его в переменную $textBirthday
        $textCity = $_POST('textCity'); // получаем значение введеное в поле ввода 2 с именем textCity и заносим его в переменную $textCity
        $textField = $_POST('textField'); // получаем значение введеное в поле ввода 3 с именем textField и заносим его в переменную $textField 

        echo " // виводим результат
              <span class="params on" id="Name">".$textField."</span> // вставляем значение переменной $textField в тег
              <span class="params on" id="Birthday">".$textBirthday."</span> // вставляем значение переменной $textBirthday в тег
              <span class="params on" id="City">".$textCity."</span> // вставляем значение переменной $textCity в тег
        ";
    ?>
-->
```